# RSpec "count" change.by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

So I was looking at: https://rubyplus.com/articles/1491-Basic-TDD-in-Rails-Writing-Validation-Tests-for-the-Model

Just seeing techniques of testing and I saw this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Article, type: :model do
  it 'is valid if title and description fields have value' do
    expect do
      article = Article.new(title: 'test', description: 'test')
      article.save
    end.to change{Article.count}.by(1)
  end
end
```

Specifically the last line: `end.to change{Article.count}.by(1)`. From reading https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-7/docs/built-in-matchers/change-matcher

It says specifically:

> The change matcher is used to specify that a block of code changes
>   some mutable state. You can specify what will change using either of
>   two forms:

Which makes sense. But were testing `Article.count` in the block of code which isn't actually "doing" anything (The `article.save` is what actually changed the `Article.count` so how exactly does this work? Does the test take a a look at whats in the block of code before it's ran and "prerun" it...the compare the `.by(1)` after?

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are two blocks of code being executed. The block of code passed to `expect`, and the block of code passed to `change`. This is what's really happening, in pseudo-code.

```
difference = 1
initial_count = Article.count

article = Article.new(title: 'test', description: 'test')
article.save

final_count = Article.count

expect(final_count - initial_count).to eq(difference)
```

I would refactor your test to be a little easier to follow as this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Article, type: :model do
  let(:create_article) { Article.create(title: 'test', description: 'test') }

  it 'is valid if title and description fields have value' do
    expect { create_article }.to change { Article.count }.by(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess the "initial count" u've defined in psuedocode...where is that actually happening in the actual rspec code? Or does Rails/Rspec just query the model before anything runs? (Cause it doesn't seem like it does, even though obviously it must see what the previous count is before somewhere...)

Comment: `Article.count` is executed twice by rspec, once before the code from the `expect` block is evaluated, and once after.

Comment: Alternate syntax: `expect { create_article }.to change(Article, :count).by(1)`